# FragmentScenario of DialogFragment, onCreateDialog not called

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, androidx-test

I want to test DialogFragment using `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` lib.
I call `launchFragmentInContainer` and `moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)`, but `onCreateDialog` is not called in this fragment.

```
    @Test
    fun `submit search - presenter state is changed`() {
        val p: PinCatsPresenter = F.presenter(PinCatsPresenter.COMPONENT_ID)!!

        launchFragmentInContainer<PinCatsDialog>().let { scenario ->
            scenario
                .moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
                .onFragment { fragment ->
                    assertFalse(p.state.isFiltered)

                    fragment.dialog!!.findViewById<SearchView>(R.id.search_field).let {
                        it.isIconified = false
                        it.setQuery("ea", true)
                    }
                    awaitUi()
                    assertTrue(p.state.isFiltered)
                    assertEquals(3, p.state.count)
                }
        }
    }
```

I debug the app, and ensured that `onCreateDialog` is called earlier than `onResume`, but in this test scenario `onCreateDialog` is not called, so `fragment.dialog` is null.

What should I call on`FragmentScenario` so my dialog would be created?

Answer (score 2):

This is described in the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing#dialog-actions). We need to call `launchFragment` instead of `launchFragmentInContainer`:

```
   launchFragment<PinCatsDialog>().let { scenario ->
       scenario
           .moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
           .onFragment { fragment ->
               // Code here
           }
    }
```